# Discuss whether the series $\sum \left[(\pi/2)^a - (\arctan n)^a\right]$ converges or not, based on the value of $a$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, divergent-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\left[ {{{\left( {\frac{\pi }{2}} \right)}^a} - {{(\arctan n)}^a}} \right]} $$
I proved that the series diverges for $a < 0 $
and that the series converges for $a = 1$ (using $\arctan n + \arctan 1/n = \pi/2$). But I can't discuss whether it converges or not for $a>0$.

Comment: You might want to show your approach to the case a = 1.

Comment: As $\arctan 1/n=1/n+o(1/n)$ I have the feeling that it diverges for $a=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x>y>0$ and $a>0$,
$$\frac{x^a-y^a}{x-y} = a\, z^{a-1},\quad z\in(y,x) $$
by Lagrange's theorem, hence by taking $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $y=\arctan n$ we have that the convergence
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^a-\left(\arctan n\right)^a\right)$$
just depends on the convergence of:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan n\right) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\arctan\frac{1}{n}.$$
However, the last series is diverging by asymptotic comparison with the harmonic series, so the original series is **never** converging for $a>0$.